# Convert strings into a list of integer

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to vectorise a bunch of words and I'm searching the faster way to do it.

Let's say I've the string `"blahbla"`, it uses 4 different letters `["a", "b", "h", "l"]`. I create a translation table `{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'h': 2, 'l': 3}` (it will remains the same for all my words.)

My goal is to convert this word to obtains: `[1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0]`

I can do this:

```
word = "blahbla"
symbols = ["a", "b", "h", "l"]
trans_table = {s: i for i, s in enumerate(symbols)}
word = [trans_table[letter] for letter in word]
```

But do you know a faster way ?

**Edit**
Has I said before, the table will remain the same, I've in reality the following table which is computed before processing all my words:

```
symbols = [' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k',
           'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w',
           'x', 'y', 'z', 'à', 'â', 'ç', 'è', 'é', 'ê', 'î', 'ï', 'ô',
           'û', 'ü']
```

Which will stays the same for every word. Sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: Is it important that the numbering of characters in translation table must be consistent?

Comment: what do you mean by consistent ?

Comment: A single dictionary access is likely as fast as you get in Python (`symbols.index(letter)` is the alternative, and likely slower). Do you need the code to run in Python? If not, you could handle the operation in C, or even vectorized assembly code. *Why* do you need to run it faster - are there billions of entries in `word`, or in `symbols`, or is this function just called millions of times per second?

Comment: I mean, can you create translation table like this: `[1, 11, 0, 7, 1, 11, 0]`. You can just use an `ord` function for this.

Comment: You could use gnu parallel with python to achieve a faster rendering, given lots of initial values.

Comment: I want to keep it consistent

Comment: Than you can't do it faster.

Comment: ok, like that I know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a string of length *n*, you can't better O(*n*) complexity. The only improvement I can see is to use the `map` operator with a built-in function, in this case `dict.__getitem__`. This will prove marginally more efficient than using a list comprehension:

```
symbols = ["a", "b", "h", "l"]
trans_table = {s: i for i, s in enumerate(symbols)}

word = "blahbla" * 100000

%timeit [trans_table[letter] for letter in word]  # 67.6 ms
%timeit list(map(trans_table.__getitem__, word))  # 59.3 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you *need* to create your own mapping? Why not just use the `ord` function that converts a unicode character to its integer value?

```
> word = 'foo'
> list(map(ord, word))
[102, 111, 111]
```

Comment: I d'like to keep the mapping consistent

Comment: What do you mean by 'consistent', are you expecting non unicode text?